# React Js File Uploader

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to integrate react-js-file-uploader in my project but cannot seem to understand how it works. I have implemented the FileManager Component functionality successfully.. But cannot get my FileUploader to work. Right now, i don't want to upload the images to a specific url but just to have a preview of the image i am about to upload on my UI which is the same implementation given on the official website of npm. Here is the link :- https://www.npmjs.com/package/reactjs-file-uploader.

I was getting an error in a method callback, so implemented the functionality in the UploadFiles section itself instead of uploadFile method. These are the errors that i am getting on the console..

[image]

Here is the second error :-

[image]

And this is my Code, i am a beginner in react..any help would be appreciated..

```
    import React from 'react'
import {FileManager, FileUploader} from 'reactjs-file-uploader'

class App extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            files: [],
        };
        // this.uploadFiles = this.uploadFiles.bind(this);
        // this.uploadFile = this.uploadFile.bind(this);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <input
                    type="file"
                    accept="image/*"
                    onChange={event => this.setState({files: this.state.files.concat(Array.from(event.target.files))}, () => console.log('Files--->', this.state.files))}
                    multiple
                />
                <FileManager
                    files = {this.state.files}
                >
                    {this.uploadFiles}
                </FileManager>
            </div>
        )
    }

    uploadFiles(files) {
        return files.map((file) => {

            return(
                <FileUploader
                key={file.key}
                file={file}
                url='https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/dpdenton/upload'
                formData={{
                    file,
                    upload_preset: 'public',
                    tags: 'App',
                }}
                readFile
            >

                 {this.fileProgress}
             </FileUploader> 


            )

        });
    }

    // uploadFile(file) {
    //     return (
    //         <FileUploader
    //             key={file.key}
    //             file={file}
    //             url='https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/dpdenton/upload'
    //             formData={{
    //                 file,
    //                 upload_preset: 'public',
    //                 tags: 'App',
    //             }}
    //             readFile
    //         >
    //         </FileUploader>

    //         console.log(file)
    //     )
    // }

    static fileProgress({

        /*
        References to the Event objects.
        Initial state is null and each propert gets assigned on Event.
         */
        uploadReady,
        uploadStart,
        uploadProgress,
        uploadComplete,
        downloadStart,
        downloadProgress,
        downloadComplete,
        error,
        abort,
        timeout,

        /*
        The sequential state of the request
        enum {
            uploadReady, uploadStart, uploadProgress, uploadComplete, downloadStart
            downloadStart, downloadProgress, downloadComplete
        }
         */
        requestState,

        /*
        Function references to start / abort request
          */
        startUpload,
        abortRequest,

        /*
        Request Object reference (XMLHttpReqeust)
         */
        request,

        /*
        Response text Object (JSON)
         */
        response,

        /*
        Data of the file being uploaded (if readData props is true)
         */
        fileData,

     })

     {
        return (
            <div>

                {fileData && <img src={fileData} width={200} alt="Preview"/>}
                {/* {startUpload && <button onClick={startUpload}>Upload File</button>} */}
                {/* {requestState && requestState} */}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: It is going to the uploadFiles without putting (). If i put (), it is showing "Cannot Read Property of undefined"

Comment: You're right. This is how the docs says. Strange syntax. Anyway.. are those 2 lines commented out on purpose? `this.uploadFiles = this.uploadFiles.bind(this);` and the follow one.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake I uncommented the this.uploadFile as that is the only method I am using...but I am still getting the same errors in my console

Comment: I have uncommented the last two lines also...but no change

Comment: in your method you're passing variable `files` to `uploadFiles`. obviously if you don't pass anything you'd get `undefined.map` in that function

Comment: But the uploadFiles is working perfectly, the files are coming I mapped it and saw the files on console...There is some error in FileUploader

Comment: That library ihaven't had a new release in 2 years. And by looking at it docs seems so strange to me. I think you should take a look at `react-dropzone` or `react-filepond`

Comment: Okay..Thank you so much for the recommended resources

Comment: I have updated my answer. Could you please check once whether it is working fine or not??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying a lot following code worked for me. **fileProgress** is a static method so we need call it with class name below. **A static method needs to be accessed on the class not an instance**. Whatever the code is they mentioned in docs everything is same except **{this.fileProgress}**

```
// My class name is FilesUpload you can mention your classname
class FilesUpload extends React.Component {

<FileUploader
            key={file.key}
            file={file}
            url='https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/dpdenton/upload'
            formData={{
                file,
                upload_preset: 'public',
                tags: 'vanilla',
            }}
            readFile
        >
            {FilesUpload.fileProgress} // YOU NEED TO CALL WITH YOUR CLASS NAME I.E APP.fileProgress THEN IT IS WORKING FINE...
        </FileUploader>
 }
```